# Why is my string vector empty

Tags: c++

Wher is my mistake I want to read a [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0RR9.png) into a string vector. using the memberfunction getFileList. Iterating it in the main the string vector is empty. I fill in only one string (buffer) to check the vector and no files are being listed. Only the following output comes:

```
Singleton cstr
//verify success in opening dir
opened? [0x1d92630 ]
[ buffer ]
itVect[ buffer ]
```

Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class Singleton
{

public:
   std::vector<std::string> singletonVect;
   Singleton();
   void buildFileList(std::vector<std::string> filesVect);
   std::vector<std::string> getFileList(void);
   static Singleton& getInstance();
};

std::vector<std::string> strings = {"lkhdf","lfdjasdlk"};
Singleton& singleObj(Singleton::getInstance());

std::vector<std::string> openDirectory(std::string path) //opening any folder and saving all file-names in a vector<string>
{
   DIR* dir;
   dirent* pdir;
   std::vector<std::string> files;
   dir = opendir(path.c_str());

   std::cout << "opened? [" << dir << " ]\n";

   while (pdir = readdir(dir)) {
      files.push_back(pdir->d_name);
   }
   return files;
}

void Singleton::buildFileList(std::vector<std::string> filesVect)
{
   std::vector<std::string> f;
   std::string buffer = "";
   f = openDirectory("myFiles"); // pass which dir to open
   for (auto i = f.begin(); i != f.end(); ++i) {
      if ((*i).find(".exe") != std::string::npos) {
         buffer = "myFiles/" + (*i);
         filesVect.push_back(buffer);
      }
   }
}

std::vector<std::string> Singleton::getFileList(void)
{
   return singletonVect;
}

Singleton::Singleton()
{
   std::cout << "Singleton cstr\n";

   buildFileList(singletonVect);
}

Singleton& Singleton::getInstance()
{
   static Singleton singleObj;
   return singleObj;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   singleObj.singletonVect = singleObj.getFileList();

   singleObj.singletonVect.push_back("buffer");

   std::cout <<"[ "<< (*singleObj.singletonVect.begin())  << " ]\n";

   for (auto itVect = singleObj.singletonVect.begin(); itVect != singleObj.singletonVect.end(); itVect++) {
      std::cout << "itVect[ " << (*itVect) << " ]\n";
   }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 3):

One problem is here:

`void Singleton::buildFileList(std::vector<std::string> filesVect)`

You're passing `filesVect` by value, which means that the function is working with a temporary.  When the function returns, all of your hard work you have adding items to the vector goes up in smoke and disappears.

Pass by reference instead:

`void Singleton::buildFileList(std::vector<std::string>& filesVect)`

This is no different than if you did this:

```
int foo(int x)
{
   x = 10;
}

int main()
{
   int myInt = 0;
   foo(myInt);
   // myInt is still 0, not 10
}
```

Note that `foo()` takes the int parameter by value.  No change was done to the caller's `int`, even though `foo()` changes the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Well simple mistake. Dont do this again. By reference:

change

```
void buildFileList(std::vector<std::string> filesVect);
```

to

```
void buildFileList(std::vector<std::string>& filesVect);
```

the same here:

```
void Singleton::buildFileList(std::vector<std::string>& filesVect)
{
   std::vector<std::string> f;
   std::string buffer = "";
   f = openDirectory("myFiles"); // pass which dir to open
   for (auto i = f.begin(); i != f.end(); ++i) {
      if ((*i).find(".exe") != std::string::npos) {
         buffer = "myFiles/" + (*i);
         filesVect.push_back(buffer);
      }
   }
}
```

and it works.